# Default values with XMLBeam

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I want to simplyfiy my XML handling with XMLBeam (https://xmlbeam.org)

So I have this XML:

```
    <column>
        <name>myname1</name>
    </column>
    <column trimvalue="true">
        <name>myname2</name>
    </column>
```

and this XMLBeam Interface class

```
 interface Column {
    @XBRead("name")
    String getName();

    @XBRead("@trimvalue")
    Boolean getTrimValues();
}
```

As you can see, only the second column hast the attribute `trimvalue`.
How can I set the default value to `false` with XMLBeam **without** changing the XML.

Currently, I always have to check for `getTrimValues()!=null && getTrimValues()==true` in an utility method but I wonder if you can implement a default value in XMLBeam, maybe like:

```
    @XBRead("@trimvalue")
    @XBDefaultValue(false) <== THIS Annotation does not exist, this is just an idea
    Boolean getTrimValues();
```

Thank you,
schube

Answer (score 0):

The way I would recommend is to use an XMLSchema and put the defaults in the schema. There is a tutorial on how to do that on the [XMLBeam project site](https://xmlbeam.org/tutorials.html#E16_Using_an_XML_schema_to_define_default_values_and_validate_the_document).

But in your case, simply change from `Boolean` to `boolean`. It will never return `null`, `false` is the default.

If you have this problem again, maybe with another type, have a look at [the API docs](https://xmlbeam.org/apidocs/). You can change the type conversion of any type and change the default value if you need. [Here](https://xmlbeam.org/t14.html) is an example for a custom type conversion.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is: There is no XMLSchema. I understand the change from Boolean to boolean for this specific datatype, but setting default values for other types (like Strings for example) would not work. Ok, it is good to know that it is not possible at the moment and I did not miss something. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: One more thing... If you have Java 8, you can use the return type `Optional<>` for any projection method. This way you can choose the default value at the point you are using the value.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!